# Simple reorder point system - multiple record generation - MS Access

Tags: ms-access, vba

First of all - great site. I have been reading through the forum for quite some time and have found many threads quite valuable. But it is time to create a thread for my own since I have not been able to find a discussion for my question.

I am building a simplified re-order point system - if inventory position drops below a certain level (the yellow level is this case) one or more purchase order lines has to be created in another table.

I have one table with the following field and data:

ItemId....Red....Yellow....Green....Multiple....Inventory position

0001.... 10.... 30.... 50.... 5.... 45

0002.... 5.... 40.... 47.... 5.... 23

0003.... 11.... 20.... 30.... 10.... 5

I would like to generate new records (in another table) based on the above fields and three records.

Basically the end result should look as the following:

ItemId....Qty....Start inv....Aggregated inventory....Prioritization

0002.... 5.... 23.... 28.... Yellow

0002.... 5.... 28.... 33.... Yellow

0002.... 5.... 33.... 38.... Yellow

0002.... 5.... 38.... 43.... Green

0002.... 5.... 43.... 48.... Green

0003.... 10.... 5.... 15.... Red

0003.... 10.... 15.... 25.... Yellow

0003.... 10.... 25.... 35.... Green

The logic is quite simple - if inventory position is less than the yellow value new order lines should be created in multiple qty (based on the multiple field) until the aggregated value (in table 2) is above the green value.

The priotization value should be based on the start inv (in tbl 2) compared to the values in red, yellow and green in tbl 1.

It would be much valuable if someone could guide me in the right direction towards an appropriate VBA design. Alternatively some kind of loop query design (but I believe that VBA is required to make the above - particularly on the loops and running sum).

Comment: I *think* I know what you are trying to accomplish, but have a couple questions: (1) Can your order be a sum of the multiples instead of multiple lines (i.e. order 25 at once)?; (2) How are you handling fulfilled orders and current inventory (i.e. item 2 has qty of 23, but you have ordered 25 more)?

Comment: Hi Wayne - thanks for the reply. Actually the total order quantity is a sum of the multiples until the aggregated inventory is above the green level. Question 2 is quite relevant but I am handling that before table one is generated. It will be incorporate into the inventory position. hope that clarifies the question :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is one solution to produce the orders. However, I disagree with the example you gave above because either the 4th order for item 002 should be 'Yellow' and not 'Green', or the first order for item 0003 should be 'Yellow' and not 'Red'. It appears you use two different sets of rules for the ranges that control the color.

I just added the Debug statements to help show what is going on. Also, you can delete/modify the code that deletes the Order data.

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit


Function Place_Order()
Dim rsIN    As DAO.Recordset
Dim rsOT    As DAO.Recordset
Dim strSQL  As String
Dim i       As Integer
Dim iOH     As Integer

i = MsgBox("Do you want to delete all orders from tblOrders (if testing, click YES).", vbYesNo, "Delete All Orders")
If i = vbYes Then
    strSQL = "delete * from tblOrders;"
    DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL
End If

Set rsIN = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tblInventory")
If Not rsIN.EOF Then
    Set rsOT = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tblOrders")
    Do While Not rsIN.EOF
        If rsIN!InventoryPosition < rsIN!Yellow Then
            ' Need to place order(s) for this item
            Debug.Print "Place order for item: " & rsIN!ItemId & vbTab & "O/H = " & rsIN!InventoryPosition & vbTab & "Yellow = " & rsIN!Yellow

'ItemId Red Yellow  Green   Multiple    Inventory position
' 0001   10     30     50       5               45
' 0002    5     40     47       5               23
' 0003   11     20     30       10               5

            iOH = rsIN!InventoryPosition
            Do While iOH < rsIN!Green
                iOH = iOH + rsIN!Multiple
                rsOT.AddNew
                rsOT!ItemId = rsIN!ItemId
                rsOT!Qty = rsIN!Multiple
                rsOT!StartInv = iOH - rsIN!Multiple
                rsOT!AggregatedInventory = iOH
                If iOH < rsIN!Red Then
                    rsOT!Prioritzation = "Red"
                ElseIf iOH <= rsIN!Yellow Then
                    rsOT!Prioritzation = "Yellow"
                Else
                    rsOT!Prioritzation = "Green"
                End If
                Debug.Print "Item: " & rsIN!ItemId & vbTab & rsOT!Qty & vbTab & rsOT!StartInv & vbTab & rsOT!AggregatedInventory & vbTab & rsOT!Prioritzation
                rsOT.Update
            Loop
        Else
            ' No order is needed for this item
            Debug.Print "No order is needed for item: " & rsIN!ItemId & vbTab & "O/H = " & rsIN!InventoryPosition & vbTab & "Yellow = " & rsIN!Yellow
        End If
        rsIN.MoveNext
    Loop
    rsOT.Close
    Set rsOT = Nothing
Else
    MsgBox "No records in tblInventory", vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "No Items To Process"
End If
rsIN.Close
Set rsIN = Nothing

' What the two tables look like:
'SELECT tblInventory.ItemID, tblInventory.Red, tblInventory.Yellow, tblInventory.Green, tblInventory.Multiple, tblInventory.InventoryPosition
'FROM tblInventory;

'SELECT tblOrders.ItemID, tblOrders.Qty, tblOrders.StartInv, tblOrders.AggregatedInventory, tblOrders.Prioritzation
'FROM tblOrders;

End Function
```

Comment: WOW - this is truly amazing! I am really grateful for all the help. I have created the VBA code in an module and corrected the headings of my tables so it matches the above. But when I execute the code it stops at the following line: rsOT!Prioritization = "Yellow" --> with the error message rsOT!Prioritization = <Item not found in the collection.>. It seems quite strange since the line above actually finds a value iOH = 28 and rsIN!Yellow = 40 which is why it goes into the elseIf decision. Have I done anything that is not correct?

Comment: And yes - you are absolutely correct. My example is not correct in the sense of the color prioritization. It is the number four line of 0002 which is not correct since the Start inventory (=38) is still below the top of yellow value (=40). Thanks for noticing this and again thank you for the help - it is really great that people are willing to help like this. thank you.

Comment: I actually found the problem - the field Prioritzation was spelled differently on my table headings. Furthermore referring back to the color prioritization I have rearranged the code a bit - and it seems to work!

Comment: I just posted the changed code - I am not sure if it correct how I have rearranged the code. But it seems to do the job :-)

Comment: My mistake with the spelling... as long as the code you now have produces the desired result, you will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit


Function Place_Order()
Dim rsIN    As DAO.Recordset
Dim rsOT    As DAO.Recordset
Dim strSQL  As String
Dim i       As Integer
Dim iOH     As Integer

i = MsgBox("Do you want to delete all orders from tblOrders (if testing, click YES).", vbYesNo, "Delete All Orders")
If i = vbYes Then
    strSQL = "delete * from tblOrders;"
    DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL
End If

Set rsIN = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tblInventory")
If Not rsIN.EOF Then
    Set rsOT = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tblOrders")
    Do While Not rsIN.EOF
        If rsIN!InventoryPosition < rsIN!Yellow Then
            ' Need to place order(s) for this item
            Debug.Print "Place order for item: " & rsIN!ItemId & vbTab & "O/H = " & rsIN!InventoryPosition & vbTab & "Yellow = " & rsIN!Yellow

'ItemId Red Yellow  Green   Multiple    Inventory position
' 0001   10     30     50       5               45
' 0002    5     40     47       5               23
' 0003   11     20     30       10               5

            iOH = rsIN!InventoryPosition
            Do While iOH < rsIN!Green
                rsOT.AddNew
                rsOT!ItemId = rsIN!ItemId
                If iOH < rsIN!Red Then
                    rsOT!Prioritzation = "Red"
                ElseIf iOH <= rsIN!Yellow Then
                    rsOT!Prioritzation = "Yellow"
                Else
                    rsOT!Prioritzation = "Green"
                End If
                Debug.Print "Item: " & rsIN!ItemId & vbTab & rsOT!Qty & vbTab & rsOT!StartInv & vbTab & rsOT!AggregatedInventory & vbTab & rsOT!Prioritzation
                iOH = iOH + rsIN!Multiple
                rsOT!Qty = rsIN!Multiple
                rsOT!StartInv = iOH - rsIN!Multiple
                rsOT!AggregatedInventory = iOH
                rsOT.Update
            Loop
        Else
            ' No order is needed for this item
            Debug.Print "No order is needed for item: " & rsIN!ItemId & vbTab & "O/H = " & rsIN!InventoryPosition & vbTab & "Yellow = " & rsIN!Yellow
        End If
        rsIN.MoveNext
    Loop
    rsOT.Close
    Set rsOT = Nothing
Else
    MsgBox "No records in tblInventory", vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "No Items To Process"
End If
rsIN.Close
Set rsIN = Nothing

' What the two tables look like:
'SELECT tblInventory.ItemID, tblInventory.Red, tblInventory.Yellow, tblInventory.Green, tblInventory.Multiple, tblInventory.InventoryPosition
'FROM tblInventory;

'SELECT tblOrders.ItemID, tblOrders.Qty, tblOrders.StartInv, tblOrders.AggregatedInventory, tblOrders.Prioritzation
'FROM tblOrders;

End Function
```